# Having problems swap positision of two image buttons

Tags: android

Suppose I have two ImageButtons in my xml file .I want to swap the position of two imageButtons after clicking any of them .
Need help .

Comment: just change the image src with one another on button click.You can apply some animation also if you want.

Comment: would u please help me to tell the syntax in .java file to change the resource?